# Text file apostrophe trouble

Tags: c

I'm attempting to read from a Project Gutenberg text file and count the total number of words. I'm currently overshooting because words with apostrophes are double counted. However the apostrophe character from the text file doesn't match the ASCII character 39, i.e. '\'', so my is_word function is working incorrectly. Any suggestion as to what that character actually is?

Note: When I go through and manually replace the apostrophes in vim, the word counter works fine.

link to text file: http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/1342

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: IIRC, in vim, goto the character and type "g8" (long time since I last used vim).

Comment: I suspect the apostrophes may be represented as Unicode Right Single Quotation Marks, U+2019.  For a UTF-8 file, these will appear to be the three bytes 0xe2, 0x80, 0x99.  But if you use a proper Unicode-aware input method (`getwchar`?), you should be able to look for the value 0x2019 (8217).

Comment: unicode 2019, UTF8 E2 80 99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer, but if you do

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
```

and then

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
```

and then call `getwchar()` or `getwc(fp)` instead of `getchar`/`getc`, and then check for the value 8217 as well as `'\''`, you might be able to get it all to work.

(It works for me.  YMMV.  Depending on your OS, you might have to use a locale string other than "en_US.UTF-8".)

(And if this does work, welcome to the wonderful world of [internationalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization).  Having gone down this road, there are several other issues you'll have to pay attention to if you want your code to work properly under all circumstances and in all locales.)

Comment: *Having gone down this road, there are several other issues you'll have to pay attention to if you want your code to work properly under all circumstances and in all locales.*  That's the understatement of the day!